# UWP C# - custom entry point executables are not supported

Tags: uwp, manifest

When I try to debug my app, it throws the error but compiles successfully when Release is selected.

```
Applications with custom entry point executables are not supported. Check Executable attribute of the Application element in the package
```

Following is the Applications tag from the manifest.

```
  <Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
      <uap:Protocol Name="myapp" />
    </uap:Extension>
  </Extensions>
</Application>
```

Edit:

For some reason stacko is not loading all manifest code so pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/FsFEJZFz

Comment: Could you please tell me are you trying to add a protocol for your UWP app so that you could launch it by protocol?

Comment: Yes but it launches another app embedded in the assets folder.

Comment: Could you please share the code that you are using to launch the UWP app?

Comment: Please check https://pastebin.com/FsFEJZFz

Comment: I don't mean the manifest file. How do you launch your UWP app? Is it from another app? What is the code that app is using?

Comment: No that is normal and executes the entry point. EntryPoint="MyApp.App". It works if I remove the second application from the manifest in debug mode.

Comment: But then it removes the custom protocol.

Comment: I'm confused about your question. Now you have an app which declare the protocol in the manifest, it gives you compile error in debug mode, right? Why there is a fulltrust capability in the manifest file?

Comment: runFullTrust is required for windows.fullTrustProcess

Comment: What is the kind of your app? Is it a UWP app or you are tiring to something else that needs runFullTrust ?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your behavior but I'm not sure why you need to add the runFullTrust. Are you trying to launch a exe file or you are a desktop bridge app?

Comment: Custom protocol points to this app "Assets\Helper.exe" so using a runFullTrust for it to execute. I'm very new to UWP so maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: I noticed that there are two different Application elements in the manifest file. What is the composition of your program? Does it contain more than one program? It looks like you are using Windows Application Packaging Project. Could you please give more details about how you created the app and what kind of your app is?

Comment: I'm very close to fixing it. Using two application tags was wrong and had to use "Windows Application Packaging Project" to use the fulltrust app. This post helped alot:  https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to launch an exe program from the UWP app.

If it is just an exe file, you could just add the runfulltrust in the manifest file of the UWP application. Make sure to put it in the `Extensions` element.

If you need to reference the exe project in your UWP app, you will need to use the Windows App Packaging Project.